# the implementation of @strongify

Tags: objective-c

```
#define strongify(...) \
    try {} @finally {} \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wshadow\"") \
    metamacro_foreach(mtl_strongify_,, __VA_ARGS__) \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")
```

I read the source code of metamacro_foreach and manually expand a case, why is SEP nothing in

strongify(). It's really kind if someone could explain this piece of code. 
source code of metamacro_foreach:

[[https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/metamacros.h#L53]](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/metamacros.h#L53%5d)

Answer (score 0):

`try {} @finally {}` only exists to make compiler happy with the extra `@` sign before the macro.

so `@strongify(...)` expand to something like

```
@try {} @finally {} 
_Pragma("clang diagnostic push") 
_Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wshadow\"") 
// something....
_Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")
```

You can remove `try {} @finally {}` from the macro and use it like `strongify(...)` and it should also work.

But I think the author of the macro want the `@` sign before it to make it looks like real Objective-C syntax because most ObjC keywords start with `@` sign. e.g. `@autoreleasepool`, `@try`, etc.

Comment: thanks for the reply, why is SEP left nothing in strongify

Comment: @JohnHanr I think SEP is for separator, and in this case, it is empty.